# Querying nested jsonb hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

I am storing jsonb on Model#data field with following structure in rails

```
{
 $action_id1: {
   $user_id1: [1,2,3],
   $user_id2: [1,2,3],
   $user_id3: [1,2,3]
 },
 $action_id2: {
   $user_id1: [1,2,3],
   $user_id4: [1,2,3],
   $user_id3: [1,2,3]
 },
 $action_id2: {
   $user_id1: [1,2,3],
   $user_id2: [1,2,3],
   $user_id3: [1,2,3]
 }
}
```

How can I query the `data` field to get all records where `$user_id2` key exists irrespective of `actiod_id` key.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will answer your questions..

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING